# Show a cover image with a description below and lots of Images android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I have implemented a news page with recyclerview which shows only image, headline and date. If user click on an specific news, the app will redirect to detail page of the news. Now in this page user will find a Cover Image of the news, which is the main photo of the news. Below this news user will read the description of that news. And below the descrion he can see lots of images related to that news, like 4 or 5 images. Here I would like to mention that the image list is not fixed for all the news. It might be 4, or 5 or 6. the page should have scroll view behavior. I have read about CollapsingToolbase layout. but. in this case in the scroll bar I can either add text or image. But what would be the most efficient way to do that. I stuck wih creating the appropriate layout for this detail page.

Comment: try this https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator and https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator and http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/06/view-pager-with-circular-indicator.html and this also https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Comment: @NileshRathod I do not want to implement any view pager here. this page should have scroll View behavior

Comment: explain in brief

Comment: A cover image, A description, and Images. User can scroll this page

Comment: than implement a  horizontal recyclerview

Comment: Any reason why you do not use webview/html?

Comment: @k3b I am very new in android developing. Is it applicable webview in this case. Because y requirement is that a cover image, description and other images of that news. All are in Verticle orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might as well use another `RecyclerView` for your images! This way you pass a list of images to the adapters and make the amount of images be dynamic.

**EDIT**

Make a layout similar to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@color/dark_blue" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Your description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then populate your RecyclerView with the other images.

Comment: Ya Recycler view is one option for image. But what could I do for a fixrd description below the cover Image. I mean how can I organise the whole thing here

Comment: Edited my answer, let me know if this is what you needed

Comment: Thanks. yes I need this type of layout. I Just added an ScrollView there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/top_seller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/image1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/large_text" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/image_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```